# text-align: center in body causing repeater to center with no override ability

Tags: asp.net, css

I have an asp.net repeater that centers in IE 7, but left justifies in FF.  I want it to left justify.  I noticed in css if I remove:

```
body {
text-align:center;
}
```

The repeater left justifies in IE.  Problem is, practically the whole site shifts left too...this is not good.  I don't want to re-write the whole site.

I have the repeater in a div with id="nav".  I added a css for nav:

```
#nav {
    text-align:left !important;
}
```

yet the repeater is still centered.  So I tried:

```
#menuRepeater 
{
    float:left;
    text-align:left !important;
}
```

It's still centered.  Damn IE.  Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what an asp.net repeater is, but in IE if you are centering a block level element using the margin rules (`margin: 0 auto`) then the parent element needs to have `text-align: center`.

Comment: I added text-align: left to the parent div and it worked. I'm not sure why the parent div has to house the text-align, but that's what I saw with the IE Developer toolbar a friend of mine just showed me. The tool ultimately showed me the actual issue, but you get the credit cause you were definitly on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact opposite problem. I want a ASP .NET repeater to center justify in Edge but it will left justify. I have tried everything. `text-align:center` , `justify-content:center` , etc...   Nothing seems to work.